# Jmeter how to test different assertion for each users

Tags: jmeter

Say I am using the csv data set config to add user simultaneously. Now I add my steps for each users it will assert different info. For example the my info screen for each user will be different and I want to verify that for each users logging in that the my info screen show the correct user info? Could anyone recommend how I could do this using jmeter? Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can parameterize [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) the same way you parameterize [Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers).

For example if you expect info screen to contain text `Welcome, Joe` where `Joe` will be different for any user you can use the following Response Assertion configuration:

[image: JMeter Response Assertion]

Where `${username}` is the variable from the CSV file.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more information on conditionally marking JMeter sample results as passed or failed.